# Query or Vlookup: Creating an auto-populated attendance list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I could really use some help.

I am trying to put together an auto-populated attendance list. Here is a version of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y2XgDolK37OfeErIb47yBIsoK0GWL8EWTLNw3lnxdwo/edit?usp=sharing

Essentially, what I would like to happen is that as a teacher rosters students on the "9th Tutoring Block" and "10th Tutoring Block" tabs using the dropdown menu, the data will automatically populate on the "Teacher1" tab. The data that I need to auto-populate is the Student Id, Email, Last Name, First Name, AND the day of the week that the student is rostered.

Additionally, I need to adjust for the fact that teachers will need to pull from both the "9th Tutoring Block" and "10th Tutoring Block" tabs.

At first, I tried a vlookup, but I could not get it to add a student to the list if they were rostered on two different days by the same teacher. So for example, if Teacher 1 rosters Student 1 on Monday and Tuesday, I need student 1 to be on the list twice, but with different day of the week labels.

Next, I tried vertically combined queries, which is the formula on Teacher1!A3. With this formula, I have not figured out how to add the correct tutoring for each student, especially students that are rostered on multiple days.

This is my current formula:

```
={QUERY('9th Tutoring Block'!A3:I138,"select A, B, D, E where F = 'Teacher1'"); QUERY('9th Tutoring Block'!A3:I138,"select A, B, D, E where G = 'Teacher1'"); QUERY('9th Tutoring Block'!A3:I138,"select A, B, D, E where H = 'Teacher1'"); QUERY('9th Tutoring Block'!A3:I138,"select A, B, D, E where I = 'Teacher1'")}
```

But it produces an error if one of the queries produces an empty output.

Comment: Player0's formula was able to solve the issue I had with pulling student data if they are rostered by the same teacher on multiple days. Any advice on how to pull the day of the week that they are rostered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(
 {IFERROR(QUERY('9th Tutoring Block'!A3:I138, 
  "select A,B,D,E where F = 'Teacher1'"), {"","","",""}); 
  IFERROR(QUERY('9th Tutoring Block'!A3:I138, 
  "select A,B,D,E where G = 'Teacher1'"), {"","","",""}); 
  IFERROR(QUERY('9th Tutoring Block'!A3:I138, 
  "select A,B,D,E where H = 'Teacher1'"), {"","","",""}); 
  IFERROR(QUERY('9th Tutoring Block'!A3:I138, 
  "select A,B,D,E where I = 'Teacher1'"), {"","","",""})}, 
  "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

or you can drop the `UNIQUE` if so...

[image]

option 2:

```
=QUERY('9th Tutoring Block'!A3:I138, 
 "select A,B,D,E 
  where F = 'Teacher1'
     or G = 'Teacher1'
     or H = 'Teacher1'
     or I = 'Teacher1'")
```

[image]

option 3:

```
=QUERY({'9th Tutoring Block'!A3:E138, FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
        '9th Tutoring Block'!F3:I138),,9^9))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5 
  where Col6 contains 'Teacher1'")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I used option 1 without the unique function and I am to pull all students that are rostered, even if they are rostered on multiple days by the same teacher.